# Aggregate function with where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a situation where I need the aggregate function to be use in the where condition for the update
statement and also for select statement.

**Example**:

## Situation 1:

```
 Update test_table
 set ID_Number = 0
 where count(ID_Number)=1; /* Not possible with where */
```

**Note**: Above script is not possible with where clause.

## Situation 2:

For example I have the following table: Test

```
 ID_Number Column1  Column2
 --------------------------
  1          XYZ      ZYX
  1          MMM      NNN
  2          III      JJJ
  3          AAA      BBB
  3          CCC      DDD
```

Now I need to show only those records who's ID_Number is appear two times.

**Expected Result**:

```
 ID_Number   Column1    Column2
 ------------------------------
  1           XYZ        ZYX
  1           MMM        NNN
  3           AAA        BBB
  3           CCC        DDD
```

**My try**:

```
 select * from Test
 group by ID_Number,Column1,Column2 
 having count(ID_Number)>1;
```

**Note**: This gives me nothing in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
   ID_Number INT NOT NULL,
   Column1 VARCHAR(50),
   Column2 VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 'XYZ', 'ZYX');
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 'MMM', 'NNN');
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 'III', 'JJJ');
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 'AAA', 'BBB');
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 'CCC', 'DDD');

-- Situation #1
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT ID_Number
   FROM   @Test
   GROUP BY ID_Number
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
UPDATE ts
SET    ts.ID_Number = 0
FROM   @Test ts
INNER JOIN cte
        ON cte.ID_Number = ts.ID_Number;

-- Situation #2
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT ID_Number
   FROM   @Test
   GROUP BY ID_Number
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT ts.*
FROM   @Test ts
INNER JOIN cte
        ON cte.ID_Number = ts.ID_Number;
```

The output is the "Expected Result" shown in the question.

For both situations, the CTE gets the `ID_Number` values that show up more than once, and that list of values is used to filter the main `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**Situation 1:**

For Updating Your Can USE `Common Table Expressions`

```
Update test_table
 set ID_Number = 0
 where ID_Number IN (
select tst.ID_Number from test_table tst join
(
select ID_Number,COUNT(*) as CNT from test_table
GROUP BY  ID_Number)d
 ON d.ID_Number=tst.ID_Number
 where d.CNT=1
)
```

**Situation 2:**

```
select tst.ID_Number,Column1,Column2 from test_table tst join
(
select ID_Number,COUNT(*) as CNT from test_table
GROUP BY  ID_Number)d
 ON d.ID_Number=tst.ID_Number
 where d.CNT>1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f66786/11)

Comment: I have not downvoted but was going to question how this was supposed to work. By filtering on `ROW_NUMBER() > 1` this query is filtering out the first row from each of the desired "groups".

Comment: Hi Ganesh_Delekar, I think there some thing wrong with the where condition : where CTE.Row=1

Answer (score 0):

First looking to your **Situation 2** your query to getting your desired output will be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Test 
WHERE ID_Number IN (select ID_Number from Test
                group by ID_Number
                having count(ID_Number)>1)
```

Now looking to your **Situation 1** you can write UPDATE query which updates columns
: ID_Number = 0 to only those records whose ID_Number records coming once as per you stated in your Update query. You can modify your update query as follows:

```
Update test_table
set ID_Number = 0
FROM test_table
WHERE ID_Number IN (select ID_Number from Test
group by ID_Number
having count(ID_Number) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
with cte as (
   select *, count(*) over (partition by ID_Number) as c
   from test_table
)
select *
from cte
where c > 1
```